# Sharepoint 2013 column validation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Have a Sharepoint list with 5 columns i.e Asset Class, Start Date/TIme, End Date/Time, Patching status, comments. I have column validation on Start Date/TIme and End Date/Time. My problem is if the data needs to be amended i need to allow them to save as is if they are amending details on the Asset Class, Patching status or the comments columnns i.e as long as they are not changing the column information on Start Date/TIme or End Date/Time.

Answer (score 0):

`JS Link` seems to be a good option for that.
[Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) is a collection of several samples. Maybe it's enough to [disable](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a/sourcecode?fileId=135185&pathId=501388593) the date fields? Otherwise, you would need to write some custom `JavaScript` according to your business logic. The collection gives you a good starting point to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use presaveaction for this, cache the original values of item, and compare in presaveaction, if the function return false, the new value can't be save.

[Check the sample](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx)